# avoid http checking when installing a home made gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a set of gems for my application.

When installing any of my own gems, the gem program will check rubugems specs (possibly for dependencies). With a verbose flag I can see messages like :

```
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Found
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
```

The issue is that I'm working on those gems, and that I package/reinstall a number of times every day, and the installation process is quite long.

As I'm pretty sure that all the external gem dependencies are satisfied, is there a way to tel gem *not to check* the dependencies from rubygems.org, and avoid, possibly slow http traffic ?

Regards,

_dl

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things like rubygems.org from being accessed as part of your build, you can use an internal gemserver like GemInABox to host the gems you'll use in your organization.

Then just make sure to pass both the --clear-sources and --source options to gem.

For example:

```
gem install bundler --clear-sources --source http://your.corporate.gemserver.here.com
```

This will allow you to keep connectivity issues and network lag out of your CI build, thereby eliminating another source of build variance.

It used to be that gem's --source option was used as the only source for gem lookups. From somewhere in 2009 onwards, it changed to combine the source supplied as an option with the default sources defined for gems, one of which is http://rubygems.org.

Sadly, that meant that if you were running gem in a machine which was walled off and couldn't even access an http proxy, you'd find gem install failing with network issues since it would get homesick and attempt to lookup http://rubygems.org even though you'd told it not to look there.

The Rubygems manual is a little behind the curve, and the --clear-source option undocumented in the manual. It's only visible if you look in the source code. I hope this gets picked up and used by others to save them some time.

Cheers
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jeweler to create the gem?

You can use `rake install` to install the gem

Comment: No we don't use jeweler, the gem is installed as a part of a process where the gem command line is invoked. So I really need a gem option and --ignore-dependencies does exactly what I need.